# Reusing JLabel for displaying text consecutively

Tags: java, jlabel

I want to display a text. When you click on that text it should take you to text2 and when you click on it, it should take you to text3, and so on. The problem with my code is that it always takes me directly to the last text. Can you guys help? Even my teacher sat with me and couldn't think of a way to do it. Heres the code:

```
package test1;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame j1 = new JFrame("Game");
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel();
        int count = 1;
        boolean chapterOver = false;

        j1.setSize(500, 500);
        j1.setVisible(true);
        j1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        j1.add(l1);
        l1.setText("text 1");
        l1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        while (chapterOver == false) {
            if (count == 1) {
                l1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        l1.setText("text2");
                    }
                });
                count++;
            }

            if (count == 2) {
                l1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        l1.setText("text3");
                    }
                });
                count++;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This question could easily be answered by stepping through your code with a *debugger*. So learn how to use it!

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I know how to use a debugger. I don't see how it is going to help me.

Comment: "It will take you to text 2" do you mean it will gain focus on textbox 2?

Comment: You do not need a while loop, your action listener will always be listening.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an okay solution:

```
static int count = 1;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
    When user clicks, it tiggers an event which tiggers  `setTextCount`
    */

    l1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


            setTextCount(l1);

        }
    });


}

public static void setTextCount(javax.swing.JLabel label){
    label.setText("text "+ (count + 1));
    count = (count + 1 )%3;
}
```

It looks like you are still a bit confuse on UI. UI programming is inversion of control. So when a user clicks on something, the UI changes the state of the program. What I am saying is, why did you add `while` loop?

Comment: Yes I am very confused about UI programming. I don't really understand your solution, though, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to use a debugger.

Either this is a lie or you don't understand your program as it executes.

Your debugger would have showed this:

```
            count++;
        }
        // count = 2 in first iteration, therefore following if never fails
        if (count == 2) {
        // this means you always _immediately_ add the second MouseListener Listener to the l1
```

And if you'd placed breakpoints inside both of the `MouseListener` methods you'd have observed that actually both are run after a click o the label.

A beginner should not mess around with random choosen Swing components. Making a `JLable` *active* by use of `MouseListener` is a bad way to start.

I suggest you (and your teacher) restart by following the official Java Tutorial on how to create GUI:    https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html